# Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation. Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I got an error while debuging a program i wrote down from a tutorial online, it is a sound synth made by the one lone coder on youtube. I'm not sure what caused it or how to fix it. I disabled pre-compiled headers witch was the first problem i encounterd.

I have tried searching online, leading me here to awnsers about code of others, i have tried going on multiple discord servers and asking there.
No luck so far. Also this is just as a little exercise to help me get back on track.

Main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "olcNoiseMaker.h"
using namespace std;
double MakeNoise(double dTime) {
        return 0.5 * sin(540.0 * 2 * 3.14159 * dTime);
}
int main() {
    wcout << "onelonecoder.com - synth part 1" << endl;
    //Get all sound hardware
    vector<wstring> devices = olcNoiseMaker<short>::Enumerate();
    //Display finding
    for (auto d : devices) wcout << "Found output device:" << d << endl;
    //Create sound machine
    olcNoiseMaker<short> sound(devices[0], 44100, 1, 8, 512);
    //Link noise function whit machine
    sound.SetUserFunction(MakeNoise);
    return 0;
}
```

olcNoiseMaker.h is just to get acces to the sound chip and bla bla.
you can see his video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgamhuQnOkM&t=134s

Running the program should result in a contenious sine wave of 540 KHz 
instead it plays it only once and gives me this error:

Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
**_Tgt** was 0xA4EFF82C. occurred

Comment: What output do you get for the `wcout << "Found output device:" << d << endl;` line?

Comment: The output is: onelonecoder.com - synth part 1 Found output device:Speakers (Realtek High Definiti

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you've posted. The error is in the third party code you downloaded from the internet (no surprise). Since you haven't posted that code it's hard to help.

Comment: O-oh, okay, here it is: https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/synth/blob/master/olcNoiseMaker.h

Comment: Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @john "*Nothing wrong with the code you've posted*" - I see a few things wrong with it. Using `std::vector` without `#include <vector>`. Using `char` strings with `std::wcout`. No bounds checking before accessing `devices[0]`.

Comment: @Nasko Far too much code for me to look through. Time to use your debugger. At the very least determine the line on which it crashes. And you can fix the issues that Remy mentions.

Comment: The program works properly, i'm not sure on how to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer, but I had this issue (Visual Studio 2019). When I built and ran the program, there was just one short beep before the program exited. The issue was that I was in the x64 Debug configuration, and that was causing the error. Once I changed to x86 Debug, it was working perfectly.

Edit: Also, in your code, you are missing the `while(1) {}` after the `sound.SetUserFunction(MakeNoise);` statement which would be needed to get the code working according to the video.